# React Native KeyBoard Close itself

Tags: react-native, keyboard, textinput

I've saw similar error because of react-native-screens, I tried multiple versions and it didn't worked, I tried to install last versions of my libraries and got even more problem (Installed the good version back after that)
I don't get where it come from

```
return (
<>
  <ImageBackground
    source={require('./assets/images/background.png')}
    style={styles.app}
  > 
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <Text>Pannel des utilisateurs.</Text>
      <Button
        style={styles.deconnect}
        onPress={() => deleteUser()}
        mode="contained">
        Déconnection
      </Button>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.textSearch}>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={text}
        placeholder={"Search ... "}
        keyboardType="default"
      />
    </View>
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <FlatList
      data={[...users].sort((a, b) => {
        return (
          (b.surname+b.name+b.email+(b.confirmed?"confirmé":"pas confirmé")+b.phone+b.role.name).toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()) -
          (a.surname+a.name+a.email+(a.confirmed?"confirmé":"pas confirmé")+a.phone+a.role.name).toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())
        );
      })}
      style={styles.data}
      numColumns={1}
      renderItem={render}
      keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index.toString()}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  </ImageBackground>     
</>
```

There is only a connection page for strapi that work and even the sorting work but I don't know why since 2days It close itself or I need to spam it to keep it open then after closing it manualy It doesn't open again if I don't click something else on the UI (like a button)

Answer (score 0):

It seem that paddingbottom make the TextInput close itself when you tap in.
I don't think it's normal thing but removing it for a margin resolved the problem